# python split string by delimiter only it is outside of quotes

Tags: python, csv, parsing

My string has the following format:

```
string = 'token1 -token2 +"token 3"'
```

I want to extract the tokens and fields as follows:

```
result = [
    'token1',
    '-token2',
    '+token 3'
]
```

I am using the `csv` module for that but unsuccessfully getting the last token as `'+"token', '3"'`

```
# for Python 2.x
try: from StringIO import StringIO
# for Python 3.x
except ImportError: from io import StringIO
import csv

f = StringIO('token1 -token2 +"token 3"')

tokens = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', doublequote=False, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

for t in tokens: print(t)
# > ['token1', '-token2', '+"token', '3"']
```

Comment: There is no exact, correct format that can be used. Colud you provide more details or any other patterns in your source csv file?

Comment: The `+` and `-` are optional and tokens get quoted if they have one or more spaces in them. this is the full pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a customer splitter for this specific case, since the format was too specific. The below code works fine for the provided inputs.

```
# for Python 2.x
try: from StringIO import StringIO
# for Python 3.x
except ImportError: from io import StringIO
import csv

f = StringIO('token1 -token2 +"token 3"')

def check_and_split(line):
    tokens = []
    is_quote = False
    token = ''
    for c in line:
        if c == ' ' and (not is_quote):
            is_quote = False
            tokens.append(token)
            token = ''
        elif c == '"':
            is_quote = True
        else:
            token += c
    tokens.append(token)
    return tokens


for line in f:
    tokens = check_and_split(line)
    for t in tokens: 
        print(t)
```

Output:

```
token1
-token2
+token 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Though the statement in `elif c == '"':` needs to be changed from `is_quote = True` to `is_quote = not is_quote` in order to handle the case where the first token has quotes

Answer (score 0):

csv isn't recognizing `+"token 3"` as a single value because the quotes don't surround the whole thing. So ensure that they do:

```
line = line.replace('+"', '"+')
```

and change `csv.QUOTE_NONE` to `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` (or just drop the `quoting` arg).